# Mathematical structure of a dictionary.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Please correct me if I am wrong. I understand that during the last couple of centuries we have put a lot of effort in trying to understand structures, and for most of them we have been able to reduce them to sets. So we have translated mathematical structures to the language of sets, that is we define other stuff using sets.

I was wondering how an effort of this style would look like if we tried to give a hierarchical meaning to a dictionary. Modern dictionaries (I Think) are prone to alot of circular arguments. I would like to know if we could just take some words for granted and then build (define) everything else up from there. What do you think those words would be? Has this question been asked before?

regards.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm, sounds,  like it may. But isn't there a part of mathematics that studies things of this nature? It kind of looks like a finitely generated group to me. Where we generate all words using the "basic" words. (here the operation would be juxtaposition of words where most sentences would prbably mean giberish

Comment: I think the application of group theory to languages would be an area of linguistics.  See, for example, http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225243144_Group_Theory_and_Computational_Linguistics/file/79e415087a24f960aa.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would picture a dictionary as a long list of words where each word has its synonyms beside it. A synonym is a word with the same / similar or related meaning.

E.G:

1. flammable / inflammable
2. alike / similar
3. bright / clever / dazzling

Comment: Isn't that a thesaurus?

Comment: Yes a thesaurus is just such a list.
However if you want to put a math twist on it then the alphabetically arranged words could be sorted with a computer program such that no word is ever repeated in the list.

Therefore you word not find
"alike / similar"
then later in the list
"similar / alike".
Each alphabetical character has a unique number attached to it in ASCII CODE.
See:>>
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Start with the concept of 'is' or 'to be' or think of it as some type of equality.  I think that's the beginning, and go from there.

But ... the best thing is that this would be a multi-valued function.  Then you want to consider the projection of this to one word with the pull-back being all the synonyms.  From there you can consider a particular choice for the synonyms on the pull-back in such a way to form a continuous function (assuming that you have a continuous function from words in the projective space) and form a section.